# Not working, GPO - Disable Offline Files on individual redirected folders

Tags: directory, redirection

I've enabled this GPO - Disable Offline Files on individual redirected folders

I've checked the registry and it's applying, but every time I redirect a folder (My Documents or My Pictures), it automatically makes them offline. I don't want to disable offline folders, I would just like the option to enable it manaually. I've checked the share and it's setup for cache mode manual.